# Writing to txt file C++

Tags: c++, file

I would like to write the words in the file until I type the word "stop", but only the first word is saved to the file.
What's the problem?

```
int main(int i)
    {
        ofstream file;
        string file_name,message;
        cout << "\nFilename: ";
        cin >> file_name;
        cout << "Write 'stop' to end writig to file" << endl;
        for(i=0; message!="stop"; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nYour message: ";
            cin >> message;
            file.open(file_name.c_str());
            file << message.c_str() << "\t" ;
        }
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Only call `file.open()` once, before the loop.

Comment: Also, your main function is illegal.

Comment: Open the file once, not every time through the loop. Opening a file will by default truncate it to zero length.

Comment: Also you might want to read up on `while` loops because the `for` loop counter `i` is unused.

Comment: Okay, now everyting is working fine, but word 'stop' is in the txt file, how to delete/not write to file only this word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
int main()
    {
        int i;
        ofstream file;
        string file_name,message;
        cout << "\nFilename: ";
        cin >> file_name;
        cout << "Write 'stop' to end writig to file" << endl;
        file.open(file_name.c_str());
        for(i=0; message!="stop"; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nYour message: ";
            cin >> message;
            if(message == "stop"){ //If you dont want word stop
               break;
            }
            file << message.c_str() << "\t" ;
        }
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

It would be better if you do something like,

```
do{
   //do stuff
   if (message == "stop")
       break;
   }while(message != "stop");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you better switch to a while loop  of the form: `while (!file.eof())`, or `while (file.good())`.

Apart from that, the for loop has to define the variable, in your case i is undefined, and must contain the range of the variable and no other variable definition (condition on message must not be inside it. It has to be an **if** condition inside the **for** loop).

```
   ...
   char word[20]; // creates the buffer in which cin writes
   while (file.good() ) {
        cin >> word;
        if (word == "stop") {
           break;
        ...
        }
   } 
   ...
```

Actually, I am not sure how it compiles at all in your case :) For future reference: **for** loop should look like this: `for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {};`

I hope it is clear!